# Google Cloud Shell and VM SSH command lines blank

Tags: firefox, command-line, virtual-machine, google-cloud-shell

In the Google Cloud Platform Console, upon clicking "Activate Cloud Shell," the bar for the command line shows up and displays "Provisioning your Google Cloud Shell Machine" and "Establishing your connection to Google Cloud Shell," but after that the entire box for the command line goes blank. It still has the option bar that displays the project name, option to open the text editor, etc. I tried going to the text editor hoping that the command line would show itself there, but the whole box remained blank.

Even worse, I started one of my virtual machines and used the SSH option from the console to connect to it, and the SSH window similarly went totally blank. Any ideas what's going wrong here? I'm using Firefox on Windows 10 and haven't had any issues using the Cloud Shell for months.

Comment: Does the problem happen at the same time if you use Chrome or Edge?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, but I was hoping to get it working in Firefox again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815984/8016720

Answer (score 0):

This was a browser compatibility problem between FF64 and the Google Cloud Shell terminal emulator library.  The SSH-in-the browser feature inside Cloud Console is using the same terminal emulator, so it was affected as well.  Both have now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Google cloud shell doesn't work with Firefox.

[image]

I waited for a whole thirty minutes and nothing happened. Thirty! I switched to Chrome and the issue was sorted out immediately.