# Cloud terminal appears empty in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I've tested this on Microsoft Edge and Chrome and its working.

[image: Screenshot]

Update: It's working now on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue currently. This is a compatibility issue with Firefox version 64.0. Previous version 63.0.3 works with Google Cloud Shell but version 64.0 released on 2018-12-11 shows Cloud Shell empty.

You can use other browser or fix it temporarily by reverting back to older Firefox version from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with Google Cloud Shell terminal emulator, but it has since been fixed.